# What does :_type_disabled at inheritance_column mean?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, single-table-inheritance

I just came across with such a line in some model in Rails:

```
self.inheritance_column = :_type_disabled
```

What does it do?

Answer (score 0):

And I realised what's the answer during writing the question. It disables [single table inheritance](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Inheritance.html), what practically means that Rails won't assume that I have a special `type` field in my model and my eventual inheritation will have consequences only on code level, not in the database.